# Is there a way to send JavaScript variables to PHP proxy handling API calls

Tags: javascript, php, proxy

I am building a single-page web application that makes a call to a third-party API (in this case the Dark Sky weather API). Because this API does not support CORS, I'm trying to write a server-side PHP proxy to make the API calls.

I need to be able to include latitude and longitude parameters in my HTTP GET request, which are gathered from the client-side JavaScript, but I'm struggling with coming up with a workflow for getting these JavaScript variables over to my PHP proxy. It seems like a pretty simple problem, but one that is new to me.

If anyone can provide basic instruction on handling this, or pointing me towards a resource that explains this problem, that would be wonderful.

I am currently using a CORS proxy to make the request, but I'd like to move away from this in production, as the API request requires a key.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding well, you just need to set those variables as a query string on the request's URL and handle them with PHP.

You just need to add them in the end of the URL as `whateverurlyouhave.com/endpoint?latitude=yourlatitude&longitude=yourlongitude`

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. Let say you are getting two lat,long from a text box.

**step 1: send the lat,long to server**

```
let lat=$('.lat').val();
let long=$('.long').val();

$.ajax({      
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://yourserver.com?lat=lat&long=long",
  "method": "GET",
  "success":function(res){
   console.log(response);
  }
});
```

**Step 2: Receive and call external API**

```
<?php
$lat =$_REQUEST['lat'];
$long =$_REQUEST['long'];
$API_KEY=""; //Your api key
$curl = curl_init();

 curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/$API_KEY/$lat,$long",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: */*",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Host: api.darksky.net",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I'm looking for, except for one thing. The console log of the response from PHP is logging the code of the PHP page itself, rather than the intended JSON object.

Comment: I hope you can handle it.